# How to use Preside as a -ion word?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, derivational-morphology

English is not my first language, so I'm finding it weird to understand a particular usage for the word 'Preside'.

I'm creating an Programme Schedule for an event and I need to add a line that indicates **Mr X is going to preside over the event**. The rest of the schedule is like so:

> 1. Address by Mr. ABC,
> 2. Inauguration by Mr. EFG
> 3. ----------- by Mr. X

I'm just not sure how to frame the sentence here. Do I write

> 1. Presiding over by Mr. X?
> 2. _____ion by Mr. X (I don't know if Preside has a `ion` form)

or something else?

Comment: Leaving the *presiding* individual aside, your use of *inauguration* here is unfamiliar to me. What kind of event is it? Is Mr. EFG perhaps giving *welcoming remarks*, or is there some sort of formal presentation he is making or some activity he is initiating?

Comment: You'd say 'Mr X was the *chair* of the meeting', or 'the meeting was *chaired by* Mr. X'. I am unaware of any -ion form of preside in common usage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Their name (comma) *presiding*.

Ideally just after naming the thing that they're presiding over. Like the title of a book and it's author, it's likely to be on the next line or at least in a smaller font (also, center justified and with less space between the two, which I can't do here).

> ## Name of the Event
>
> **Mr. X, presiding.**
>
> 1. Address by Mr. ABC,
> 2. Inauguration by Mr. EFG

---

exhibit (a).

> Bailiff announces: "All rise. The Court of ________ is now in session, the Honorable Judge ________ presiding."
>
> – [basic_trial_procedures.pdf](http://www.cnmibar.net/mock_trial/2004/basic_trial_procedures.pdf)

Answer (score 11):

I don't know of a form of *preside* that meets your needs here, but I'm not sure this is a word choice problem. The other examples on the schedule indicate actions with defined beginnings and endings relative to the event. The whole event will, presumably, be presided over by Mr. X, or at least the portions that come after the address and inauguration.

So if what you are trying to express is that Mr. X will preside over the event, it seems odd to include that as a sequential item in this list. The actual event itself (the one over which Mr. X will preside) seems like a better fit for that line item on the list. A note could be included indicating that it will be *presided over by*, *facilitated by*, *overseen by*, *moderated by*, ..., Mr. X. Exactly what the event is may suggest a particular word for that specific application.

So, perhaps:

> 1. [...]
> 2. [...]
> 3. Panel discussion of Topic Q, moderated by Mr. X
>
> or: 3. Panel discussion of Topic Q-- Presider: Mr. X

Or similar.

Answer (score 3):

Describe the **event** over which Mr X is presiding:

*3. ___ event, presided over by Mr X.*

The others in your sequence are each some THING and a person. The verb (what the person does) is only implied:

1. Address, **given** by Mr ABC,
2. Inauguration, **introduced** (led?) by Mr EFG.

For #3, the action (verb) is presiding, and the person is Mr X. But what is the THING over which Mr X presides?  (Is it a meeting of some sort?)